# What is a "universal app"?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been reading about React and Redux, and they mention "universal apps".  e.g.:

> "You’ll probably want a (de)serialization mechanism for writing universal apps and hydrating their state from the server..."
>   (From http://rackt.org/redux/docs/introduction/PriorArt.html)

What is a universal app?

Comment: IMO a universal app would be system agnostic application which can interface with your React//Redux, eg a mobile App, linux app, windows app..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, universal app refers to those web applications with the ability to render in both the server or the client, depending on circumstances.

Sometimes can also be referred to as "isomorphic apps".

The more complete explanation from https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-isomorphic-tools:

> What is a web application? I would define it as a box with a bunch of
>   inputs (keyboard events, mouse events) and a display as an output. A
>   user walks into your website and your web application renders a "page"
>   on his display.
>
> At first all the rendering used to happen on the server. But then
>   "AJAX" came (in 2005) and it opened a possibility of moving all
>   rendering logic to the client (user's web browser) leaving the server
>   with just serving API calls (data fetching, data modification, etc).
>
> And so numerous javascript frameworks emerged to serve the purpose of
>   client side rendering and routing. But then everybody realised that
>   this new way of building web applications broke search engine indexing
>   because the search engines didn't talk any javascript.
>
> Then the age of super-responsive websites came and also the iPhone
>   emerged and the battle for milliseconds began. And everybody noticed
>   that client side rendering introduced unnecessary data fetching
>   roundtrips on the first page load: the web browser loaded markup
>   templates and scripts first and then asked the server for the actual
>   data to display.
>
> So it became obvious that web applications need to be "isomorphic"
>   ("universal"), i.e. be able to render both on the client and the
>   server, depending on circumstances. It was quite manageable: one just
>   had to write the rendering logic in such a programming language that
>   is able to run both on client and server. One such language is
>   javascript.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know this concept (i mean universal app) you should first know how spa applications wroks!!

**how spa applications wroks?**

imagine a scenario, we have a web application that have builded in spa fashion !
in such applications when a user send a request to server for example when he/she want to see the index page, server return a html page to client that this page contains nothing!!! (i mean its have no data ,you know that every page is composite of html tags + data and data is our for example last blog posts or products in e-commerce websites)
in spa when user send request to server, server return the html page with no data ,after page rendering your application send ajax request to server and fetch those data(in our exmaple last blog posts,okay?)
spa applications work in this way! after knowing this we can learn how universal app works?

**so how Universal app works?**

universal apps works like spa applications but these applications check the request, but  for what purpose? actually they want to know user sended request is him/her first request for this url or not?(i know it was difficult description so let  me describe it with an example)

again imagine a scenario, user want to see **mysite.com/about** page,okay? universal apps checks the url, if sended url is for the first time that has been sended by user universal app will render that page on the server side(render the page with its tags and data then send it to the client.okay?)and in next requests if user want to see about page again in universal app this page not render on the server side actually in next requests pages will render on client side.

**conclusion:
in universal app first view dynamically render on the server and after first load application turn to spa!**